# Creating a form dynamically in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamically-generated

I have a form that is created by default. That has been designed to the way I want it to, now I want to create a new form dynamically, but I want to set the new form to look exactly like the one created by default. Programming in VB.NET (WinForms) and Environment VS2010.

I have so far:

```
Dim newWindow As new Form

newWindow = Me

newWindow.Show()
```

I know there should be something like newWindow inherits Form1 but can't figure out where to put it =S

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Form's name of the Form you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently creating a Form, then assigning your current Form to it. You need to `New` up another instance of your Form then you can show it, along with your Main Form.

```
Dim newWindow As New Form1 'Name of my Default Form's Class assuming Form1.
newWindow.Show()
```